# How to convert a user_input into a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need some help this and I'm sure when this is answered it will be pretty simple that I didn't think of. But here it is:

I'm trying to get this code:

```
forename = [input("Forename: ")]
forenameFirstLetter = forename[0]

email = str(forenameFirstLetter) + "." + surname + "@TreeRoad.net"
print ("This is the students email address:" + email)
```

to print:

```
J.Smith@TreeRoad.net
```

Instead I'm getting this error: `TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly`

so how would I go about forename into a list so I can print the first letter and then back into a string so i can add it to other string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## What you did wrong:

What you where trying to do was creating a list whose only element was a string. When it is a list, `forename[0]` will take the first (and only) element of that list (Just the string as if it was taken directly from `input()`), but not from the string.

---

## How to fix it:

It is not necessary to convert it to list, slice notation allows to use:

```
forename = input("Forename: ")
forenameFirstLetter = forename[0]
```

So, now it's unnecessary to convert to string later:

```
email = forenameFirstLetter + "." + surname + "@TreeRoad.net"
print ("This is the students email address:" + email)
```

---

## To understand better slicing strings:

```
 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | (index)
 f | o | o | . | (string)
```

When you slice a string:

```
s = "foo."

s[0] #is "f" because it corresponds with the index 0
s[1] #is "o"
s[2] #is "o"
s[0:2] #takes the substring from the index 0 to 2. In this example: "foo"
s[:1] #From the start of the string until reaching the index 1. "fo"
s[2:] #From 2 to the end, "o."
s[::2] #This is the step, here we are taking a substring with even index.
s[1:2:3] #You can put all three together
```

So the syntax is `string[start:end:step]`.

For use in lists is very similar.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are trying to convert the string to a list you can just slice the string itself.

Change this line:

```
forename = [input("Forename: ")]
```

to

```
forename = input("Forename: ")
```

By doing this you are getting the first letter of the string. I would recommend reading [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-and-slice-strings-in-python-3) article on string slicing to learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
forename = input('Forename: ')
surname = input('Surname: ')

email = forename[0] + "." + surname + "@TreeRoad.net"
print ("This is the students email address:" + email)
```

You can also use simpler to read string formatting:

```
email = '%s.%s@TreeRoad.net' % (forename[0], surname)
```

Comment: It's been tagged Python 3.x, so `raw_input` doesn't exist... and if they were using 2.x, then their `input` would be causing a different exception than the one given...

Comment: My bad, didn't notice it's in regard to Python3. Corrected now.

Comment: Any reason for the old-style string formatting? Could use `email = '{0[0]}.{1}'.format(forename, surname)`... and in the print, since it's a function, just use: `print('This is the students email address:', email)` (eg: no need for the string concatenation)

Comment: That would also work, I am just personally used to '%s' style.

Answer (score -1):

Don't take input inside the list take string as input and apply split function on it and it will be converted into list.